# Identifying the backend provider of a logged in user

Tags: django, django-socialauth

With django-social-auth, is there a good way to find out the backend provider of a logged in user? Is finding the corresponding UserSocialAuth object supposedly the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views, try:

```
request.user.social_auth.values_list('provider')
```

to get a list of the user's connected backends.

Answer (score 3):

The last login provider is stored in the session using the key `social_auth_last_login_backend` by default, otherwise yes, checking the `UserSocialAuth` instances is the preferred way by doing `user.social_auth.filter()`.

Both methods can be combined by doing:

```
user.social_auth.filter(provider=request.session['social_auth_last_login_backend'])
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I'm very new: what's 'user' here? Is it the User class in contrib.auth?

Comment: @Kate, yes, it's a instance from the `User` model in `contrib.auth`. You can access the current logged in user in a view by doing `request.user`.

Comment: This gets <UserSocialAuth: theusername>, not the name of the backend

Comment: My bad, misunderstood the question.