# django-social-auth : connected successfully, how to query for users now?

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

I have started using https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth  and been successfully able to login via twitter, google and facebook.

**Needed**

I need to query about the logged in user in order to do more things, which Model I shall be using for that?

I don't see any examples for that

Thank you

**Update**

@Omab, I did not understand how this would work, can you please help. When I login with twitter, the callback goes to following code

```
@login_required
def done(request):
    """Login complete view, displays user data"""
    ctx = {
        'version': version,
        'last_login': request.session.get('social_auth_last_login_backend')
    }
    logging.warn('context - ' + str(ctx))
    logging.warn('request - ' + str(request))
    return render_to_response('home.html', ctx, RequestContext(request))
```

**Can you tell me how can I access to user instance here?**

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The app stores the social account details using the `UserSocialAuth` model, to retrieve any instance just do:

```
user.social_auth.filter(provider="...")
```

Where:

- `user` is a User instance (`request.user` for current logged in user)
- `provider` is a string with the provider name (facebook, twitter, etc)

The `UserSocialAuth` instance stores the needed tokens to call the needed API:

```
print user_social_auth.tokens
{...}
```

Comment: I updated the code, still not getting it clearly, can you please help?

Comment: Hi @omab, can you please help with this. I still don't get anything, I have updated the code as well

Comment: @daydreamer, in a view you can access the user instance doing `request.user`. If it's logged in, then the instance will respond with `True` when calling `request.user.is_authenticated()`.

Comment: @omab in my case this method does not return the same instance as directly importing UserSocialAuth from social_auth.models. With this method I miss some fields like extra_data, tokens... What am I getting wrong?

Comment: @Bastian, not sure, depends of the instance type you get, maybe there's another app clashing?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by K-man, you can try this ([Identifying the backend provider of a logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11166240/identifying-the-backend-provider-of-a-logged-in-user)):

```
    request.user.social_auth.values_list('provider')
```

Other values that you can find in the values_list include: **id**, **uid** (for ex. facebook user id), **user**, **extra_data** (which contains the **access_token**)